# Веб-сервер для Ruby On Rails

Tags: веб-сервер, ruby

Собственно где его качать, что он из себя представляет и как настраивать, что бы сайт на Ruby on Rails был виден из вне?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby-on-Rails - это каркас разработки MVC веб-приложений для Ruby. Он может сочетаться с разными веб-серверами: Apache, Nginx и возможно другими. Начать можно с ознакомления с тем, что такое Ruby-on-Rails, например, [здесь](http://www.rubyonrails.ru/).

- [Ruby on Rails и Apache](http://alexwinner.blogspot.com/2010/06/ror-ruby-on-rails-apache2.html)
- [Rails + Nginx + Unicorn](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/ror/120368/)

Comment: Я знаю, что такое Ruby и Ruby on Rails, просто писал поздно и спать хотелось. В общем, спасибо за ссылки, особенно за RoR+Apache. А есть что то подобное для Windows?

Comment: Для Windows есть [Instant Rails](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_Rails).

Answer (score 0):

"Встроенный" в rails сервер - webrick отлично подходит для обучения и разработки,а для продакшен версии вам поможет heroku - платформа,на которой очень легко развернуть своё rails приложение (кстати,там свой сервер - puma). 
Если вам интересно почитать о развертывании rails приложения на heroku,то почитайте либо на их сайте, либо http://railstutorial.ru/, здесь вам нужны главы про git и heroku.

Comment: Не совсем так. На хероку вебсервер можно выбирать, он является, условно, частью приложения и указывается в гемфайле. Рекомендуется использовать Puma, но есть также Unicorn, Rainbows, Thin...

Answer (score -1):

Для обучения хватит встроенного сервера. Чтобы "был виден извне" прежде всего заведите VPS, это самый простой и удобный вариант.(имхо, сервер из своего домашнего компа, если вы об этом, не оптимальный вариант) 
Далее если на сервере нужна поддержка php, то это, например apache + passenger, если нет, то рекомендуют nginx + puma